# Parsing cells containing Line Feed Characters

Tags: vba, excel

[Link to *sanitized* xls on dropbox if test data is needed](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6b3ym0kk23a9431/WDExampleattempt.xlsx?dl=0)

Essentially the reports I work with aren't bad -

[image]

The issue is the way it exports to excel -

[image]

With the problem being that these cells are filled with LF characters breaking apart the data entries in the cells (usually a listing of employees in format `empID / emp name`. There's really no rhyme or reason as to where it places the LFs - sometimes there are three in a row.

A lot of the time for analysis I need to use this data but first I need each person to have their own data (the reports get a lot bigger). Since I'm constantly writing and rewriting ways to do it, I figured I'd give it a shot at CR. I'm sure there's plenty to be improved.

One note - apparently when you set a range to an inputbox range and the user hits cancel, it errors before assigning anything into the range. I could not find any other way to handle it, so I put it in its own function to avoid any other errors that occur.

All one module. The top module would be called. I know the licensing conflict here, no need to mention it.

```
Option Explicit
'==========================================
'MIT License
'Copyright (c) <2016> <Raymond Wise> <https://github.com/RaymondWise/Excel-Workday-Report-Parser> @raymondwise
'==========================================
Public Sub ParseColumnFromWorkday()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = 1

    Dim workingRange As Range
    Set workingRange = UserSelectRange(lastRow)

    If workingRange Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim workingColumn As Long
    workingColumn = workingRange.Column
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim cellToParse As Range
    Dim stringParts() As String

    For currentRow = lastRow To 2 Step -1
        Set cellToParse = Cells(currentRow, workingColumn)
        stringParts = Split(cellToParse, vbLf)
            If Len(Join(stringParts)) = 0 Then GoTo SkipLoop
        cellToParse.Value = stringParts(0)
        Dim i As Long
            For i = 1 To UBound(stringParts)
                If Len(stringParts(i)) > 0 Then
                    cellToParse.EntireRow.Copy
                    cellToParse.EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
                    cellToParse.Offset(-1) = stringParts(i)
                End If
            Next i
SkipLoop:
    Next currentRow
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

Supporting Cast

```
Private Function UserSelectRange(ByRef lastRow As Long) As Range
    Set UserSelectRange = Nothing
    Dim columnToParse As Range

    Set columnToParse = GetUserInputRange
    If columnToParse Is Nothing Then Exit Function

    If columnToParse.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "You selected multiple columns. Exiting.."
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim columnLetter As String
    columnLetter = ColumnNumberToLetter(columnToParse)

    Dim result As String
    result = MsgBox("The column you've selected to parse is column " & columnLetter, vbOKCancel)
    If result = vbCancel Then
        MsgBox "Process Cancelled."
    Exit Function
    End If

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, columnToParse.Column).End(xlUp).Row

    Set UserSelectRange = Range(Cells(2, columnToParse.Column), Cells(lastRow, columnToParse.Column))

End Function

Private Function GetUserInputRange() As Range
    'This is segregated because of how excel handles canceling a range input
    Dim userAnswer As Range
    On Error GoTo inputerror
    Set userAnswer = Application.InputBox("Please select a single column to parse", "Column Parser", Type:=8)
    Set GetUserInputRange = userAnswer
    Exit Function
inputerror:
    Set GetUserInputRange = Nothing
End Function


Private Function ColumnNumberToLetter(ByVal selectedRange As Range) As String
    Dim columnLetter As String
    Dim rowBeginningPosition As Long
    rowBeginningPosition = InStr(2, selectedRange.Address, "$")
    columnLetter = Mid(selectedRange.Address, 2, rowBeginningPosition - 2)
    ColumnNumberToLetter = columnLetter
End Function
```

This isn't posted on the repo yet, just wanted to hit the gauntlet here first.

Comment: One flaw I've recognized is handling errors if the user's input range is not in my expected format. E.g `C:C` or `$C:$C`

Comment: Just a note that I **will** get around to reviewing this, but I've been a bit swamped so it'll have to wait until next week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This "guard clause" does not need to be a *block*:

> ```
> If workingRange Is Nothing Then
>     Exit Sub
> End If
> ```

Inlining the `Exit Sub` makes it clearer that it's intended to be a "quick sanity check" and not something that's meant to eventually grow with special handling and additional code (like a block does) - in fact, it would be consistent with what you have in other places:

```
If columnToParse Is Nothing Then Exit Function
```

---

Indentation is uncalled for here:

> ```
>     Dim i As Long
>         For i = 1 To UBound(stringParts)
> ```

The declaration of `i` and the `For` loop are technically at the same "level", and should be lined up.

```
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(stringParts)
```

---

Looking again at this validation part:

> ```
> Set columnToParse = GetUserInputRange
> If columnToParse Is Nothing Then Exit Function
>
> If columnToParse.Columns.Count > 1 Then
>     MsgBox "You selected multiple columns. Exiting.."
>     Exit Function
> End If
> ```

I think this might actually be better off in an error handler.

```
Set columnToParse = GetUserInputRange
If columnToParse Is Nothing Then Err.Raise ParseError.InputRangeIsNothing
If columnToParse.Columns.Count > 1 Then Err.Raise ParseError.MultipleColumnsSelected
```

Where `ParseError` could be a `Private Enum` that defines error codes for your implementation, typically starting with `vbObjectError + 42`.

And then the body of the procedure can focus on the "happy path" - while the error handler can `Select Case` on the error number, and handle as needed:

```
Case Error.InputRangeIsNothing
    Resume CleanExit
Case Error.MultipleColumnsSelected
    MsgBox "Multiple columns are selected. Please select only one.", vbExclamation
Case Else
    MsgBox "An error has occurred: " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume CleanExit
```

---

> ```
> If Len(Join(stringParts)) = 0 Then GoTo SkipLoop
> ```

This is pretty much *the* only acceptable use for a `GoTo` instruction - simulating a `Continue` statement.

But before doing that, I'd fix the indentation:

> ```
>     For currentRow = lastRow To 2 Step -1
>         Set cellToParse = Cells(currentRow, workingColumn)
>         stringParts = Split(cellToParse, vbLf)
>             If Len(Join(stringParts)) = 0 Then GoTo SkipLoop
>         cellToParse.Value = stringParts(0)
>         Dim i As Long
>             For i = 1 To UBound(stringParts)
>                 If Len(stringParts(i)) > 0 Then
>                     cellToParse.EntireRow.Copy
>                     cellToParse.EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
>                     cellToParse.Offset(-1) = stringParts(i)
>                 End If
>             Next i
> SkipLoop:
>     Next currentRow
> ```

...and add some breathing space... and heck, I'd pay the price for the extra nesting and remove that `GoTo`.

```
    For currentRow = lastRow To 2 Step -1

        Set cellToParse = Cells(currentRow, workingColumn)
        stringParts = Split(cellToParse, vbLf)

        If Len(Join(stringParts)) > 0 Then
            cellToParse.Value = stringParts(0)

            Dim i As Long
            For i = 1 To UBound(stringParts)
                If Len(stringParts(i)) > 0 Then
                    cellToParse.EntireRow.Copy
                    cellToParse.EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
                    cellToParse.Offset(-1) = stringParts(i)
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next currentRow
```

...and then I'd extract a small private method for it:

```
Private Sub WhateverThisDoes(stringParts(), ByVal cellToParse As Range)
    cellToParse.Value = stringParts(0)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(stringParts)
        If Len(stringParts(i)) > 0 Then
            cellToParse.EntireRow.Copy
            cellToParse.EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
            cellToParse.Offset(-1) = stringParts(i)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

...which removes the nesting in the outer loop, and leaves you with smaller functions that do fewer things:

```
    If Len(Join(stringParts)) > 0 Then WhateverThisDoes stringParts, cellToParse
```

Comment: I was running into `type mismatch array or user-defined type expected` on the `If Len(Join( ...` line because when I `Dim stringParts() as String` it needs to be `as Variant` to be able to be passed as an argument, apparently.

Comment: Or maybe I can just `ByRef partsOfString() As String` so they are the same type? No, wait, I have to use string or I get a mismatch on `stringParts = Split()`. Split outputs strings, which a variant should be able to take. Maybe it's because the variant isn't sized?

Comment: @Raystafarian You can dim an array in 2 ways. `Dim array() As Type` or `Dim array as Variant: array = Array()`. You can pass the former to an argument expecting the latter (a variant), but you **cannot** pass the latter to an argument expecting the former. This is why I stick to declaration #2 for all of my arrays and arguments.

Comment: @Zak for some reason I was under the impression that I should be giving it a type if I know what type it will be, but I don't remember the reason. So I usually completely avoid `variant` - correctly or incorrectly.

Comment: Neither way is "correct", both have tradeoffs, but you **do** have to pick one and stick to it if you want to avoid compile errors.

Comment: I use #2 because it gives far more flexibility in manipulating arrays, putting arrays in arrays, stuff like that, but it does mean you have to add your own type-checking/validation.

Comment: @Raystafarian If you want some short test code to demonstrate what causes the compile errors, see [here](http://pastebin.com/PpRxQSLp)

Answer (score 2):

At first, answer of Mat's Mug is great, I agree with it, below you can find additional suggestions:

### Readability

Best practice to keep declarations together at the beginning of the sub / function and don't spread it across the code

---

> This is pretty much the only acceptable use for a GoTo instruction -
>   simulating a Continue statement.

For me the only acceptable use is within `On Error GoTo` where you can't avoid it. In all other cases it makes the logic of the code difficult to follow.

### Performance

> `stringParts = Split(cellToParse, vbLf)`

If you remove consecutive `vbLf` characters before `Split()` that makes your later code simpler. For that you can either:

- use simple loop:

  `dim CellContent as String, NewCellContent as String
  CellContent = CellToParse.Value
  NewCellContent = (Worksheetfunction.Substitute(CellToParse,vbLf & vbLf,vbLf))

  Do Until CellContent = NewCellContent

      CellContent = NewCellContent
      NewCellContent = Worksheetfunction.Substitute(NewCellContent,vbLf & vbLf,vbLf)

  Loop
  StringParts = Split(CellContent,vbLf)`
- use VB regular expression (need to include reference to "Microsoft VBSCript Regular Expression 5.5)

---

> ```
> cellToParse.EntireRow.Copy
> cellToParse.EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
> cellToParse.Offset(-1) = stringParts(i)
> ```

Most time consuming parts of VBA macros are generally worksheet manipulation (including read / write, insert / delete ranges...). As your array doesn't contain empty items now, you can get rid of `For`:

```
CountSringParts = UBound(StringParts) - LBound(StringParts) + 1  
With cellToParse
    .EntireRow.Copy
    If CountStringParts>1 Then
        .Offset(1,0).Resize(CountStringParts-1,1).EntireRow.Insert 
    End If
    .Resize(CountStringParts,1).Value=StringParts
End With
```

Comment: All right, I feel kind of dumb about this, but I'm struggling with the "simple loop". `newstringparts` is `long` and `stringparts()` will need to be a variant rather than an array of strings? Or the `stringparts` should be the `celltoparse`?

Comment: I've written that too quickly, please see update.

Comment: Ah ha, that's much more clear and makes more sense, I was trying to do it in the wrong place.