# Parsing excel cells containing line feed characters

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, enum

**This is a direct follow up to [Parsing cells containing Line Feed Characters](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/125698/parsing-cells-containing-line-feed-characters).**

---

[Link to *sanitized* xls on dropbox if test data is needed](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6b3ym0kk23a9431/WDExampleattempt.xlsx?dl=0)

Essentially the reports I work with aren't bad -

[image]

The issue is the way it exports to excel -

[image]

With the problem being that these cells are filled with LF characters breaking apart the data entries in the cells (usually a listing of employees in format `empID / emp name`. There's really no rhyme or reason as to where it places the LFs - sometimes there are three in a row.

A lot of the time for analysis I need to use this data but first I need each person to have their own data (the reports get a lot bigger).

I implemented most changes in the answers from last time, but I've never worked with `Enum` before ***or*** custom error handling. Also, this was initially developed in 2010, but this time I wrote it in 2016, if that matters.

---

#### Code

All one module. Two procedures - parse into columns and parse into rows.

```
Private Enum ParseError
    InputRangeIsNothing = vbObjectError + 42
    MultipleColumnsSelected = vbObjectError + 43
    ProcessCancelled = vbObjectError + 44
    NoOverwrite = vbObjectError + 45
    NoData = vbObjectError + 46
End Enum

Public Sub ParseIntoColumns()
'Parse column to the right (text to columns)
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim confirmOverwrite As String
    confirmOverwrite = MsgBox("Do you want to overwrite all data to the right of your selection?", vbYesNo)
    If confirmOverwrite = vbNo Then Err.Raise ParseError.NoOverwrite

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = 1

    Dim workingRange As Range
    Set workingRange = UserSelectRange(lastRow)
    If workingRange Is Nothing Then Err.Raise ParseError.InputRangeIsNothing
    Dim workingSheet As Worksheet
    Set workingSheet = workingRange.Parent
    Dim workingColumn As Long
    workingColumn = workingRange.Column

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    workingRange.TextToColumns _
    Destination:=workingRange, _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierNone, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, _
        Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, _
        Comma:=False, _
        Space:=False, _
        Other:=True, OtherChar:=vbLf
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    With workingSheet.UsedRange
        .WrapText = False
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case ParseError.InputRangeIsNothing
            MsgBox "Process cancelled: You have not selected a range.", vbExclamation
        Case ParseError.MultipleColumnsSelected
            MsgBox "Process cancelled: You may not select more than 1 column at a time", vbExclamation
        Case ParseError.ProcessCancelled
            MsgBox "Process cancelled", vbExclamation
        Case ParseError.NoOverwrite
            MsgBox "Process cancelled: Please alter your data structure to allow overwriting cells to the right of your selection.", vbExclamation
        Case ParseError.NoData
            MsgBox "Process cancelled: your selection does not have data to parse", vbExclamation
        Case Else
            MsgBox "An error has occured: " & Err.Number & "- " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    End Select

End Sub


Public Sub ParseIntoRows()
'Parse column downward, inserting rows
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = 1

    Dim workingRange As Range
    Set workingRange = UserSelectRange(lastRow)

    If workingRange Is Nothing Then Err.Raise ParseError.InputRangeIsNothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim workingColumn As Long
    workingColumn = workingRange.Column
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim cellToParse As Range
    Dim stringParts() As String
    Dim cellContent As String
    Dim replacementCellContent As String
    Dim numberOfParts As Long

    For currentRow = lastRow To 2 Step -1
        Set cellToParse = Cells(currentRow, workingColumn)
        If Not IsEmpty(cellToParse) Then
            cellContent = cellToParse.Value
            replacementCellContent = Replace(cellContent, vbLf & vbLf, vbLf)

            Do Until cellContent = replacementCellContent
                cellContent = replacementCellContent
                replacementCellContent = Replace(cellContent, vbLf & vbLf, vbLf)
            Loop

            stringParts = Split(cellContent, vbLf)
            numberOfParts = UBound(stringParts) - LBound(stringParts) + 1
            If numberOfParts > 1 Then CreateNewRows stringParts(), numberOfParts, cellToParse
        End If
    Next currentRow

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case ParseError.InputRangeIsNothing
            MsgBox "Process cancelled: You have not selected a range.", vbExclamation
        Case ParseError.MultipleColumnsSelected
            MsgBox "Process cancelled: You may not select more than 1 column at a time", vbExclamation
        Case ParseError.ProcessCancelled
            MsgBox "Process cancelled", vbExclamation
        Case ParseError.NoOverwrite
            MsgBox "Process cancelled: Please alter your data structure to allow overwriting cells to the right of your selection.", vbExclamation
        Case ParseError.NoData
            MsgBox "Process cancelled: your selection does not have data to parse", vbExclamation
        Case Else
            MsgBox "An error has occured: " & Err.Number & "- " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    End Select
End Sub
```

Supporting cast:

```
Private Sub CreateNewRows(ByRef partsOfString() As String, ByVal numberOfParts As Long, ByVal cellToParse As Range)
    With cellToParse
        .EntireRow.Copy
        .Offset(1, 0).Resize(numberOfParts - 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        .Resize(numberOfParts, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(partsOfString)
    End With
End Sub


Private Function UserSelectRange(ByRef lastRow As Long) As Range
    Set UserSelectRange = Nothing
    Dim columnToParse As Range

    Set columnToParse = GetUserInputRange
    If columnToParse Is Nothing Then Err.Raise ParseError.InputRangeIsNothing
    If columnToParse.Columns.Count > 1 Then Err.Raise ParseError.MultipleColumnsSelected

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, columnToParse.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    If lastRow < 2 Then Err.Raise ParseError.NoData
    Dim columnLetter As String
    columnLetter = ColumnNumberToLetter(columnToParse)

    Dim result As String
    result = MsgBox("The column you've selected to parse is column " & columnLetter, vbOKCancel)
    If result = vbCancel Then Err.Raise ParseError.ProcessCancelled

    Set UserSelectRange = Range(Cells(2, columnToParse.Column), Cells(lastRow, columnToParse.Column))
End Function


Private Function GetUserInputRange() As Range
    'This is segregated because of how excel handles cancelling a range input
    Dim userAnswer As Range
    On Error GoTo InputError
    Set userAnswer = Application.InputBox("Please click a cell in the column to parse", "Column Parser", Type:=8)
    Set GetUserInputRange = userAnswer
    Exit Function
InputError:
    Set GetUserInputRange = Nothing
End Function


Private Function ColumnNumberToLetter(ByVal selectedRange As Range) As String
    'Convert column number to column letter representation
    Dim rowBeginningPosition As Long
    rowBeginningPosition = InStr(2, selectedRange.Address, "$")
    Dim columnLetter As String
    columnLetter = Mid(selectedRange.Address, 2, rowBeginningPosition - 2)

    'Handles if the user selected an entire column
    If Right(columnLetter, 1) = ":" Then
        ColumnNumberToLetter = Left(columnLetter, Len(columnLetter) - 1)
    Else: ColumnNumberToLetter = columnLetter
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### General

**1 -** The first line in `UserSelectedRange` is setting the return value to its default.  At this point in the function it is already `Nothing`:

```
Private Function UserSelectRangeO(ByRef lastRow As Long) As Range
    Set UserSelectRange = Nothing    '<- Does nothing
```

Similarly, in `GetUserInputRange()` you do this if `Application.InputBox` throws:

```
    '...
    Exit Function
InputError:
    Set GetUserInputRange = Nothing
End Function
```

But if it throws, `GetUserInputRange` is never set. This function can be simplified to...

```
Private Function GetUserInputRange() As Range
    'This is segregated because of how excel handles cancelling a range input
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetUserInputRange = Application.InputBox("Please click a cell in the column to parse", _
                                                 "Column Parser", Type:=8)
End Function
```

...and at that point I'm not sure I see why you wouldn't just inline it because you are using the return value of `Nothing` to throw a different error anyway:

```
If columnToParse Is Nothing Then Err.Raise ParseError.InputRangeIsNothing
```

**2 -** There isn't any need for `UserSelectedRange` to return `lastRow` by reference. You can simply get the last row from the selected `Range` itself. Since you aren't even using `lastRow` in `ParseIntoColumns`, it allows you to get rid of this dead code in that procedure:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = 1
```

**3 -** `MsgBox` returns a `VbMsgBoxResult`, which is an `Integer`.  When you make tests of the return value, you are implicitly cast it to a `String`, then comparing it to an `Integer` (`vbCancel`), which implicitly casts it ***back*** to an `Integer`:

```
Dim result As String
result = MsgBox("The column you've selected to parse is column " & columnLetter, vbOKCancel)
If result = vbCancel Then Err.Raise ParseError.ProcessCancelled
```

If you need to store the return value, declare it as the appropriate type:

```
Dim result As VbMsgBoxResult
```

If you don't (for example if you're only testing it once), you can simply omit the variable declaration and test the return value directly:

```
If MsgBox("The column you've selected to parse is column " & columnLetter, _
          vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
    Err.Raise ParseError.ProcessCancelled
End If
```

**4 -** I'd put your `ParseError` enumeration in its own module and make it public instead of private. That way if you have other procedures that use custom error numbers you both easily can reuse them and avoid the possibility of collisions in error numbers.

**5 -** Named parameters after line continuations should be indented consistently. This is incredibly difficult to read:

```
workingRange.TextToColumns _
Destination:=workingRange, _
DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierNone, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, _
    Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, _
    Comma:=False, _
    Space:=False, _
    Other:=True, OtherChar:=vbLf
```

**6 -** Consider using a regular expression to remove duplicate line feeds in `ParseIntoRows`. This can also avoid the possible bug if the data contains a `vbCr`. Since you immediately split the result, I'd use a function like this...

```
'Needs a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions x.x
Private Function SplitLinesNoEmpties(target As String) As String()
    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = "[\n]+"
        .MultiLine = True
        .Global = True
        SplitLinesNoEmpties = Split(.Replace(Replace$(target, vbCr, vbLf), vbLf), vbLf)
    End With
End Function
```

...instead of: `Do Until cellContent = replacementCellContent`

Then you can simply use `stringParts = SplitLinesNoEmpties(cellContent)` to get your array.

**7 -** Guard clauses should be in the procedure that they guard - not in the calling procedure.  I'd move this code...

```
stringParts = Split(cellContent, vbLf)
numberOfParts = UBound(stringParts) - LBound(stringParts) + 1
If numberOfParts > 1 Then CreateNewRows stringParts(), numberOfParts, cellToParse
```

...to `Sub CreateNewRows`:

```
Private Sub CreateNewRows(ByRef partsOfString() As String, ByVal cellToParse As Range)
    Dim bottom As Long
    Dim top As Long
    bottom = LBound(partsOfString)
    top = UBound(partsOfString)
    If top <= bottom Then Exit Sub

    With cellToParse
        .EntireRow.Copy
        .Offset(1, 0).Resize(top - bottom, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        .Resize(numberOfParts, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(partsOfString)
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that this does a couple things - it avoids the need to add one to the `UBound` - `LBound` calculation and then just subtract it again. If you're testing to see if an array has at least 2 elements, `UBound` > `LBound` is sufficient (and protects from cases where `LBound` and\or `UBound` is negative). It also explicitly protects against the case of `UBound(Split(vbNullString))`, which returns -1. This leads me to...

**8 -** Your guard clauses have a very subtle bug. Before you process the cell, you use this test:

```
Set cellToParse = Cells(currentRow, workingColumn)
If Not IsEmpty(cellToParse) Then
    cellContent = cellToParse.Value
    '...
```

`IsEmpty` isn't doing what you think it is here.  It doesn't test whether a ***cell*** is empty - it tests whether the `Variant` passed to it is equal to `vbEmpty`.

```
Private Sub TleBug()
    Cells(1, 1).Formula = "=" & Chr$(34) & Chr$(34)  ' =""
    Debug.Print IsEmpty(Cells(1, 1))                 'False
    Debug.Print Cells(1, 1).Value = vbNullString     'True
End Sub
```

If you need to test whether a cell evaluates to `vbNullString`, do it explicitly:

```
Set cellToParse = Cells(currentRow, workingColumn)
cellContent = cellToParse.Value
If cellToParse <> vbNullString Then
    '...
```

**9 -** You have another (less) subtle bug. If you use `Application.InputBox` to have the user select the range to work with, you can't use the global `Range` or `Cells` collections - they ***have to*** be qualified. The reason is that you yield control to the user, who is free to select a cell in a different Workbook than the one that was active when the macro started.

```
Private Sub TleBugTwo()
    Dim target As Range
    'User selects a cell in a different Workbook
    Set target = Application.InputBox("Select cell", "Input", Type:=8)
    Dim globalRange As Range
    Set globalRange = Range("A1")
    Debug.Print globalRange.Worksheet Is ActiveSheet      'True
    Debug.Print target.Worksheet Is globalRange.Worksheet 'False
End Sub
```

### User Interface

**1. `GetUserInputRange()` doesn't display appropriate errors**

If the user simply hits "OK" when the `Application.InputBox` is displayed, Excel shows this error dialog:

[image: Error if empty]

**2. The range selection interface duplicates Excel functionality**

Note that this is more a matter of personal preference than anything, but if Excel already provides an interface to select a cell or range of cells, why duplicate that?  I'd simply use the existing `Selection` object when the macro starts.  You're already prompting the user to confirm that the `Range` that they selected when prompted is the one they want to work on, so why not just skip that entire process and use the `Selection` object instead?

### Errors

@Zak already addressed the big issue with the error handling, so I'll nitpick a little instead.

**1. Duplicated code**

Your error handlers in `ParseIntoColumns` and `ParseIntoRows` are identical, and only display the error condition to the user.  I'd recommend extracting that section to it's own Sub:

```
Private Sub DisplayErrorMessage(Err As Object)
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case ParseError.InputRangeIsNothing
            MsgBox "Process cancelled: You have not selected a range.", vbExclamation
        Case ParseError.MultipleColumnsSelected
            MsgBox "Process cancelled: You may not select more than 1 column at a time", vbExclamation
        Case ParseError.ProcessCancelled
            MsgBox "Process cancelled", vbExclamation
        Case ParseError.NoOverwrite
            MsgBox "Process cancelled: Please alter your data structure to allow overwriting cells to the right of your selection.", vbExclamation
        Case ParseError.NoData
            MsgBox "Process cancelled: your selection does not have data to parse", vbExclamation
        Case Else
            MsgBox "An error has occured: " & Err.Number & "- " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    End Select
End Sub
```

Then you can simply do this for your error handlers:

```
CleanUp:
    'Do stuff
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    DisplayErrorMessage Err
    Resume CleanUp
```

**2. User cancellation is not an error condition**

I'd consider this section to be an abuse of the error handler:

```
Dim confirmOverwrite As String
confirmOverwrite = MsgBox("Do you want to overwrite all data to the right of your selection?", vbYesNo)
If confirmOverwrite = vbNo Then Err.Raise ParseError.NoOverwrite
```

I'm not even sure that you need to display any sort of confirmation that the process has been cancelled.  My personal expectation would be that it would simply exit after I told it not to continue:

```
If confirmOverwrite = vbNo Then Exit Sub
```

Comment: @Raystafarian - Re #2 I was referring to `ParseIntoColumns()` - lastRow isn't used in that procedure.  Since you are only using it in `ParseIntoRows()`, you can grab the `lastRow` from the returned range there with something like: `lastRow = workingRange.Cells(workingRange.Parent.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: This is a lot to go over, than you. Re: 2 - it's passed back to `parseintorows`. 3 - I had no idea I could declare that type thanks! 7: I was avoiding the call of the procedure, but maybe that call costs less than your suggestion.

Comment: 8 - if a cell has `LF` in it, `isempty(range)` is `true` whereas setting it to a variable and `isempty(var)` is `false`. 9 - I see what you mean, how is that corrected?

Comment: @Raystafarian - I'm not sure I understand `Cells(1, 1) = vbLf: Debug.Print IsEmpty(Cells(1, 1))` gives `False`.  My point was that `IsEmpty()` is testing whether a given variable, cast to a `Variant`, has a VARTYPE of VT_EMPTY. It isn't a reliable way of testing to see if Range.Value evaluates to `vbNullString` because a `Range` isn't empty if it contains a formula.

Comment: So if a report, for instance, spits out a (invisible) vbLF into every cell and I want to avoid processing those, how would I manage that? I think I understand you, but this is new information to me

Comment: @Raystafarian - That's a different test that I think both of us missed ;-).  You'd need to test to see if `cellContent = vbLF` before you perform the `Split`.

Comment: Thanks for all this, I put a bounty up that I'll award you- I think you put in the effort to justify a bounty. I'm still working on all of this, but I'm sure I'll get this thing up for review *at least* one more time :)

Answer (score 3):

### Your error-handling is going to cause more errors

The relevant principle here is **Single Point of Exit**.

In essence, there should only ever be **one** place where execution of any method stops.

Your problem is here:

```
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case ParseError.InputRangeIsNothing
            MsgBox "Process cancelled: You have not selected a range.", vbExclamation
        Case ParseError.MultipleColumnsSelected
            MsgBox "Process cancelled: You may not select more than 1 column at a time", vbExclamation
        Case ParseError.ProcessCancelled
            MsgBox "Process cancelled", vbExclamation
        Case ParseError.NoOverwrite
            MsgBox "Process cancelled: Please alter your data structure to allow overwriting cells to the right of your selection.", vbExclamation
        Case ParseError.NoData
            MsgBox "Process cancelled: your selection does not have data to parse", vbExclamation
        Case Else
            MsgBox "An error has occured: " & Err.Number & "- " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    End Select
End Sub
```

If your sub runs without errors, these operations will happen:

```
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

But, if you `goto ErrHandler`, then you will get a messagebox, and then the Sub will exit **without** running those lines.

Now, here it's only `CutCopyMode` that will persist. Not the end of the world. But it could easily have been `EnableEvents` or `Calculation`.

---

Personally, I prefer the following Structure for these situations:

```
    Sub DoThing()

        On Error Goto CleanFail

        [Code]

        [Code]

        [Code]

        [Code]

CleanExit:

        [Clean Up]
        Exit Sub

CleanFail:

        [Error Handling]
        [Error Handling]
        Resume CleanExit

    End Sub
```

This way, we can always guarantee that the code will exit the procedure via `CleanExit` and so any clean-up code we put there will **always** be called.

Answer (score 3):

**ColumnNumberToLetter**
What happens if the user selects an entire *row*? Your function will currently  return a row number. In cases where an entire row is selected, you can't even work around it by using `selectedRange.EntireColumn.Address` as Excel actually returns `$1:$1048576`?!?!

Once you handle the special case of an entire row selection, you can avoid the need to special-case an entire column selection by using `InStrRev` (note the arguments are passed in a different order).

```
address = selectedRange.EntireColumn.Address
colBeginPosition = InStrRev(address, "$", 2) + 1
columnLetter = Mid(address, colBeginPosition)
```

**Persistence**
Your code is explicitly disabling and re-enabling properties like `DisplayAlerts` and `ScreenUpdating`. If your code ever forms part of a larger process, you might be resetting the properties prematurely. You should try to persist the values at the outset, and restore to *those* values, rather than explicitly setting them back to defaults or any specific value. Take a look at the class I [posted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117037/vba-class-to-persist-and-restore-excel-application-properties) that helps with persisting and restoring these properties.

**Block Syntax and statement separators**
My preference is to *never* use single-line `If` statements, but I understand the usage in limited cases. You also have some `If..Else` blocks where the `If` is not single-lined, but the `Else` uses a statement separator. Your code can quickly become unreadable with this syntax, I'd suggest changing to:

```
If Right(columnLetter, 1) = ":" Then
    ColumnNumberToLetter = Left(columnLetter, Len(columnLetter) - 1)
Else
    ColumnNumberToLetter = columnLetter
End If
```

Comment: That EntireColumn thing baffled me, so I posted a SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777170/when-an-entire-row-is-selected-why-does-selection-entirecolumn-address-return-a

Comment: I'm confused about the row argument, it should break on the selection containing more than one column, so a row can't be passed, can it? Re: persistence - thanks, I will take a look at that.

Comment: Emphasis added: *Once **you** handle the special case of an entire row selection*. i.e. I haven't handled that case (or the case of *all* cells, or *all* columns), and you'll have to do something like `If Not IsNumeric(columnLetter) Then`